# How to sort image files according to a metadata file using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I would like to sort 10000 of image files of the same group into a specific folder.

The information of all image files is in a metatdata file (c:/metadata.csv).

A metadata file (metadata.csv) is made like this;

```
**image_ID**    **Group**
ISIC_0034267    nv
ISIC_0034266    nv
ISIC_0034265    nv
ISIC_0034264    nv
ISIC_0034263    mel
ISIC_0034262    mel
ISIC_0034261    nv
ISIC_0034260    nv
ISIC_0034259    bkl
ISIC_0034258    nv
ISIC_0034257    nv
ISIC_0034256    mel
ISIC_0034255    bcc
ISIC_0034254    nv
ISIC_0034253    mel
ISIC_0034252    bkl
```

. so on

And, all image files are named after "image_id" (ISIC_XXXXXXX.jpeg).

What I want is to sort these image files (ISIC_XXXXXXX.jpeg) according to the variable, "Group" (nv, mel, bkl,...) ! In a metadata file (HAM10000_metadata.csv), there are seven different values of "Group" (akiec, bcc, bk1, mel, df, vasc, nv).

Therefore, I want to put these 10,000 image files with a same value of "Group" into 7 different folders according to the metadata file which contains the macthed value of "Group" of every image file.

How can I do this task by Python?
(all files are located at c:/ and I would like make new seven folders which are named after of "Group")

I don't know how to make a script.

I start a script like this. But I can't figure out how to finish the script.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import os
from shutil import move

meta_ham = pd.read_csv('/metadata.csv')

keyword = "meta_ham[image_id]"

from_folder = r"c:/"
to_folder = r"c:/???"

for i in os.listdir(from_folder):
    if keyword in i:
        move(os.path.join(from_folder, i), os.path.join(to_folder, i))
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to Python. I found several functions to solve this problem. But, I could not go on~

Answer (score 1):

Simply make the folders as necessary:

```
# base folders / template destinations
from_folder = "c:/"
to_folder_base = "c:/images"

# read in CSV file with pandas
meta_ham = pd.read_csv('/metadata.csv')

# iterate through each row of csv
for index in range(meta_ham):
    # get image name and corresponding group
    img_name = meta_ham[index]['image_ID'] + ".jpeg"
    keyword = meta_ham[index]['Group']
    # make a folder for this group, if it doesn't already exist. 
    # as long as exist_ok is True, then makedirs will do nothing if it already exists
    to_folder = os.path.join(to_folder_base, keyword)
    os.makedirs(to_folder, exist_ok=True)
    # move the image from its original location to this folder
    old_img_path = os.path.join(from_folder, img_name)
    new_img_path = os.path.join(to_folder, img_name)
    move(old_img_path, new_img_path)
```

Comment: This code did help me to make a final code that worked. Thank you for your help!